# Problems using a shared library

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I am following the explanation in [this page](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) and [this page](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) trying to build and use shared libraries on Ubuntu Linux.

I am building the libraries and application using a cross-compiler on my PC, than copying the files to the target system and running there.

Finally, I am at the stage where all symlinks are defined correctly and the I am able to run the application - but not in the required form.

Let's say that I have a shared library `libtest.so.1.0` in a directory `/home/ysap/libs`. I then created the symlinks `libtest.so.1` and `libtest.so` in the same directory, both pointing to the library file.

In the directory `/home/ysap/apps` I have an application program `app.e` that uses the `test` library.

Now, to run the application, I can type:

```
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ysap/libs ./app.e
```

and the application runs nicely. However, I'd like to eliminate the assignment, so I tried typing:

```
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ysap/libs
> ./app.e
```

but unfortunately I get an error message, saying:

`./app.e: error while loading shared libraries: libtest.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I also tried typing:

```
> ldconfig -n /home/ysap/libs
```

and

```
> sudo ldconfig -n /home/ysap/libs
```

but it does not help.

**What am I doing wrong? How can I make app.e run w/o the variable assignment?**

---

**Update 1**:

The application uses the `mmap()` call, so it has to be run with *sudo* priviledge. The actual invocation line is:

```
> sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ysap/libs ./app.e
```

Is it possible that the `export`-ed variable is not updated in the *sudo* environment?

---

**Update 2**:

Output of `ldd ./app.e`:

```
libtest.so.1 => /home/ysap/libs/libtest.so.1 (0xb6faa000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6f85000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.so.6 (0xb6ea4000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0xb6fb7000)
```

Comment: What is the ouptup of: ldd ./app.e ?

Comment: @coelhudo - please see update 2 in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sudo problem is as @duskwuff states, but if you want to compile an application, and not need to modify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, when linking the application you can use the `$ORIGIN` variable, which is recognized by most recent versions of linux.

If all the libraries are in the current directory, then when you link the application, you use the extra option:

```
-Wl,-R'$ORIGIN'
```

You need to quote the option to prevent it being expanded by the shell when compiling.

If you're putting it into a `Makefile` then you use:

```
-Wl,-R\$$ORIGIN
```

the `$$` is for make to use a $, the `\` is to prevent the shell that is invoked from the command line expanding the variable before passing it into the command.

You can use any symbolic path reference, so if you had a structure where binaries were in `bin/` and libraries were in `lib/`, you can use `$ORIGIN/../lib`.

This works for `dlopen` as well, so it will find libraries when they are being dynamically loaded at run-time

Comment: Thenks. So... echoing $ORIGIN on both machines returns an empty string. In the build script (which is *not* on the target machine), I tried a few versions of this option, but I keep getting a build error. Basically, I am trying to provide the path on the target machine, but on the build machine this path does not exist so the linker spits an error. Does the -R$ORIGIN option expect only relative paths?

Comment: You're trying to pass the value '$ORIGIN' into the linker without it being expanded by the shell, so if you're using a shell script to perform the compile, you need to single quote it, e.g. -Wl,-R'$ORIGIN' - I had put the single quotes around the text, which I thought would explain what needed to be done

Comment: OK, I think I found the problem. I mistakenly used forward-quotes instead of back-quotes around that option. Once corrected, it seems to be fine now.

Comment: I ended up using the `-R` option with the absolute path to the `/home/ysap/libs` directory and it works. So, now I have the following three options: 1) Decide at build-time were the shared libs will be on run-time. 2) Set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable at every invocation. 3) Wrap the application with a script.

Comment: All three options are sub-optimal. I wish there was a way to export the path to the sudo shell...

Comment: You should be using single forward quotes `'` to prevent the shell expansion of the `$ORIGIN` variable, the `-R` option expects a parameter, so if the parameter gets expanded, then it will fail. In your compile case, you should use `-Wl,-R'$ORIGIN/../libs'`, and it should work. You can check the RPATH of a binary using `readelf -a app.e | grep RPATH` - it should list the RPATH containing `$ORIGIN`; if it's missing that value then you've not compiled it correctly. The alternative is to relink the application at deploy time (which is what oracle does/did)

Comment: the `-Wl,-R'$ORIGIN/../libs'` surely works fine. I replaced it with the absolute path just to be able to move the application around `-Wl,-R'/home/ysap/libs'`.

Comment: I assume that once I move the shared libraries to one of the standard installation libraries, then all this mess will become redundant, right?

Comment: Yes, that is true, if they are put into a standard location for shared libraries (and a ldconfig run to rebuild the ld.so.cache file) then this mess becomes redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Loading libraries from a user-specified path is a security risk, so `sudo` always strips out all `LD_` environment variables, including `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: I see, thanks. So, what is the solution to this problem, if any? Am I doomed to assigning this variable every time? Is the only workaround creating a wrapper script??

Comment: You will need to either create a wrapper script, or relink the executable such that you no longer need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the 2nd option (if something to add to @Petesh's answer)?

Comment: The solution is to install the library in a location that is known